# Как проверить, имплементирует ли переменная интерфейс?

Tags: golang

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли способ определить имплементирует ли переменная/тип интерфейс в golang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в Go, реализация интерфейса является неявной. поэтому используется конструкция вида `var _ myInterface = &myImplementation{}`

```
type T struct{}
var _ I = T{}       // Проверка, что T имплеменирует I.
var _ I = (*T)(nil) // Проверка, что *T имплеменирует I.
```

Обычно это указывают, чтобы ошибки были выявлени во время компиляции уже.